# BadImageFormatException when loading custom assemblies in TFSBuildServiceHost

Tags: dll, tfs, build, x86

I'm having issues while loading custom assemblies in TFSBuildServiceHost.
When the Agent Service try to start, it fails loading custom assembly with a BadImageFormatException.

The custom assembly is a x86 generated DLL.
In the Agent property, I added a x86 tag, like this :

[image]

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What bitness is the machine the TFS Build Agent is installed on? If it's x64 the TFS process will be 64-bit and won't be able to load an x86 assembly.

Comment: Is there any way to force the TFS process to start in 32 bits ?

Comment: Effectively no; the TFS Build Agent is compiled as Any CPU so it runs as the same bitness as the host operating system.  Either you need to recompile your custom DLL as Any CPU (or x64), or you need to install the Build Agent onto a 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: We are using the HP OTA API, only available in 32 bits, so we can't compile our DLL as Any CPU...

Comment: Looks like your only option is to try a 32-bit OS or calling out to an external process that is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post

http://blog.bitcollectors.com/adam/2012/10/sgen-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-an-assembly-with-an-incorrect-format-tfs-2010/

Basically, you will need to change your Activities platform from Auto to x86.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly my problem. My problem comes when I load my dll, not when I use my activity